# A mixed two way repeated measures ANOVA post hoc

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, post-hoc

I am measuring the difference between two questionnaires (one before a distraction task and another after) between two different conditions (talking vs not talking). I have conducted a mixed repeated measures anova test and found the interaction  and the main effect significant. I was wondering how I should proceed with my analysis? Should I just report the pairwise comparisons using Bonferroni? Or do I do a paired t test? Sorry if this is a silly question but data is not my strongest point!